# Log Spring webflux types - Mono and Flux

Tags: spring, logging, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am new to spring 5.

1) How I can log the method params which are Mono and flux type without blocking them?

2) How to map Models at API layer to Business object at service layer using Map-struct?

**Edit 1:**
I have this imperative code which I am trying to convert into a reactive code. It has compilation issue at the moment due to introduction of Mono in the argument.

```
    public Mono<UserContactsBO> getUserContacts(Mono<LoginBO> loginBOMono)
    {

     LOGGER.info("Get contact info for login: {}, and client: {}", loginId, clientId);

    if (StringUtils.isAllEmpty(loginId, clientId)) {
      LOGGER.error(ErrorCodes.LOGIN_ID_CLIENT_ID_NULL.getDescription());
      throw new ServiceValidationException(
          ErrorCodes.LOGIN_ID_CLIENT_ID_NULL.getErrorCode(),
          ErrorCodes.LOGIN_ID_CLIENT_ID_NULL.getDescription());
    }

    if (!loginId.equals(clientId)) {

      if (authorizationFeignClient.validateManagerClientAccess(new LoginDTO(loginId, clientId))) {
        loginId = clientId;
      } else {
        LOGGER.error(ErrorCodes.LOGIN_ID_VALIDATION_ERROR.getDescription());

        throw new AuthorizationException(
            ErrorCodes.LOGIN_ID_VALIDATION_ERROR.getErrorCode(),
            ErrorCodes.LOGIN_ID_VALIDATION_ERROR.getDescription());
      }
    }

    UserContactDetailEntity userContactDetail = userContactRepository.findByLoginId(loginId);
    LOGGER.debug("contact info returned from DB{}", userContactDetail);
    //mapstruct to map entity to BO
    return contactMapper.userEntityToUserContactBo(userContactDetail);
  }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about the problem with a code sample? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for a bit of help on that.

Comment: added the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.
If you want to add logs you may use .map and add logs there. if filters are not passed it will return empty you can get it with swichifempty

```
loginBOMono.filter(loginBO -> !StringUtils.isAllEmpty(loginId, clientId))
          .filter(loginBOMono1 -> loginBOMono.loginId.equals(clientId))
          .filter(loginBOMono1 -> authorizationFeignClient.validateManagerClientAccess(new LoginDTO(loginId, clientId)))
          .map(loginBOMono1 -> {
              loginBOMono1.loginId = clientId;
              return loginBOMono1;
          })
          .flatMap(o -> {
             return userContactRepository.findByLoginId(o.loginId);
          })
```

Comment: Thanks. I reached up to an extent.  Could you please check this one 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852733/reactor-bubblingexception-in-place-of-custom-exception

Comment: I used  loginBOMono.log("", Level.INFO, true)  but it is not logging anything.

Comment: if you are talking about reactive programming in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852733/reactor-bubblingexception-in-place-of-custom-exception
is not best example for reactive programming.
if you want to log you can use .map and use Spring  boot Log
if you want it asynchronous you can create a util with an EmmiterProcessor
if you want simple logs you can use reactor .log() operator

Comment: I am quite new to reactive programming. Could you please correct my mistakes in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852733/reactor-bubblingexception-in-place-of-custom-exception

Comment: im not fully understanding your code i think is better to use ResponseEntity with error code and not throwing errors

Comment: I am working on the service layer to throwing business specific exceptions.

Comment: ye but why your are throwing exception you can do like this 
  .map(layer1 -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(layer1))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(ResponseEntity.noContent().build()));

Comment: My plan is to handle these exception at the API layer using controller advice