# Reactor BubblingException in place of Custom Exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, junit5

I am throwing an custom exception from the subscribe consumer but in the test case I am getting reactor.core.Exceptions.BubblingException.

**part of code:**

```
 return loginBOMonoValidated.map(this::checkAuth).map(login -> getUserContactsBOMono(login));

private LoginBO checkAuth(LoginBO loginBO) {

    if (!loginBO.getClientId().equals(loginBO.getLoginId())) {

      LoginDTO loginDTO = new LoginDTO(loginBO.getLoginId(), loginBO.getClientId());
      authorizationRemoteClient
          .validateManagerClientAccess(Mono.just(loginDTO))
          .subscribe(authClientConsumer);
      return new LoginBO(loginBO.getClientId(), loginBO.getClientId());
    } 
      else return loginBO;
  }

private Consumer<Boolean> authClientConsumer =
  bol -> {
    if (!bol) {
      logger.error(ErrorCodes.LOGIN_ID_VALIDATION_ERROR.getDescription());

      throw new AuthorizationException();
    }
  };
```

**Test**

```
Throwable exception =
        assertThrows(
            AuthorizationException.class,
            () -> {
              Mono<UserContactsBO> contact =contactInfoService.getUserContacts(Mono.just(new LoginBO("123456789", "1234")));
              contact.subscribe();
            });
```

Expected :**.**.**.AuthorizationException

Actual:reactor.core.Exceptions.BubblingException

Comment: Have you tried _expecting_ `BubblingException.class` and then accessing the _cause_ of the `BubblingException` via `exception.getCause()`?

Comment: I don't want BubblingException . I am expecting a AuthorizationException which I have thrown from the code.

Comment: Yes, I know. But... your `AuthorizationException` is likely _wrapped_ in the `BubblingException`. So, since you cannot prevent Reactor from creating the `BubblingException`, you should try what I suggested to find out if your `AuthorizationException` is fact the _cause_ of the `BubblingException`. That is the only way to test such scenarios.

Comment: Are you expecting your `validateManagerClientAccess` call in `checkAuth` to throw an exception if invalid? Because right now it will immediately return (`subscribe` is asynchronous) and happily return a new `LoginBO` instance. Also your test should use `block()` rather than `subscribe()` (tests must be synchronous)